# NPM error E404 when try to start create-react-app and installing react-dev-utils

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I got error when run command `create-react-app react-app`...

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: react-dev-utils@https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dev-utils/-/react-dev-utils-5.0.2.tgz
```

node version: 8.11.4

npm version: 5.6.0

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install below first globally and the run the react create cmd

step 1: npm install -g react-dev-utils@https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dev-utils/react-dev-utils-5.0.2.tgz

step 2: npx create-react-app my-app

your application will up and running.

Answer (score 0):

(remove the "/-/" from the URL) and run the command below

```
 npm install -g react-dev-utils@https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dev-utils/react-dev-utils-5.0.2.tgz
```

Then try to run again

```
 create-react-app react-app
```

Answer (score 0):

on windows os, uninstall node completely then install the latest one again. I solved my issue like that and works like a charm..